# First papers on holomorphic functions

Tags: mathematics, biographical-details, discoveries, complex-analysis

Briot and/or Cauchy are often said to have written the first papers on holomorphic functions, explicitly discussing them as such and their special properties.

Which papers are these? When and where were these published?

Comment: If you can find a copy at a library (or do what I did a few weeks ago, which was to buy a copy, although it set me back a couple of months in book buying due to its cost), you'll want to look at Bottazzini/Gray's recent book [**Hidden Harmony - Geometric Fantasies: The Rise of Complex Function Theory**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1461457246).

Comment: I requested it from a university library. Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to F.Klein's "Lectures on the development of mathematics in the 19th century" Cauchy created this theory (by studying the convergence of series in the complex plane) in his *Cours d'Analyse* from 1821 ( [Series 2, Volume 3 of his collected works](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90195m.r=.langFR)). A direct predecessor (but with a lack of rigour seems to be Lagrange) and also Klein declares that these things were known at this time - but seemingly as "folklore".

Comment: Incidentally, had the*Cours* on my to-read list for years, since Truesdell in a book wrote it's worth reading... Now I recall, a book by Painleve from 1900 dated the theory to Cauchy, but in 1840s... Only one way to find out. I'll update this comment once I go through it in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 5):

The theory of analytic (holomorphic) functions was indeed created by Cauchy. Briot-Bouquet book was also very influential, in particular they introduced the modern terminology ("meromorpic functions" for sure, perhaps also the term "holomorphic", and such things as poles, removable and essential singularities etc.)

Their book is Theorie des fonctions doublement periodiques et en particulier, des fonctions elliptiques, 1859 (first edition). Available free on Internet.

Remark. In the old books they used to distinguish analytic, holomorphic, regular and monogenous functions. Nowadays this is all the same. Some people like analytic, others holomorphic, while regular and monogenous are out of date.

Cauchy's papers on holomorphic functions start in 1814 and continue to the 1840-th. Wikipedia says that he "created this theory single handed" and most mathematicians would agree. You can see some references on Cauchy's early work in Wikipedia, and I suppose his collected papers are available online (He was only slightly less prolific than Euler:-)

Comment: The 2nd edition of Briot-Bouquet (1875), with a new title Théorie des fonctions elliptiques, introduced the words holomorphic and meromorphic.  They were not in the 1st edition. Their 2nd edition popularized pole, which was due to Neumann (1865). The term essential singularity is due to Weierstrass (1876). In addition to monogenic, you left out monodromic and synectic; all three are due to Cauchy (1850s). What a crazy zoo of terminology there was before it was determined that all these kinds of functions (without infinite values) were the same thing so we could stop using many of the words.

Comment: My main reference on the terminology is Bottazzini and Gray's "Hidden Harmony -- Geometric Fantasies: The Rise of Complex Function Theory", supplemented by Gray's "The Real and the Complex: A History of Analysis in the 19th Century" and "Mathematics of the 19th Century: Geometry, Analytic Function Theory" (Kolmogorov and Yushkevich ed.).