# Analytic and holomorphic functions, definitions and foundations?

Tags: mathematics, complex-analysis

If you search for the definition of analytic and holomorphic functions in books and online, you get crosses between two definitions (one involving taylor series and one differential) I can find no clear consensus on which definition holds for analytic and which for holomorphic.

I know they are mathematically equivalent but I want to know how they where originally defined? (please could you give a reliable source with your answer)

Comment: Taylor series definition is the earliest, see First papers on holomorphic functions thread http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/first-papers-on-holomorphic-functions?rq=1

Comment: Umberto Bottazzini and Jeremy Gray, **Hidden harmony—Geometric fantasies. The rise of complex function theory**. Springer, 2013.